# How do I space out FormControl

Tags: css, material-ui

```
 <FormControl fullWidth component="fieldset" inputRef={register({ required: true })}>
                    <FormLabel component="legend">Format</FormLabel>
                    <RadioGroup row aria-label="format" name="format" onChange={changeHandler} inputRef={register({ required: true })}>
                      <FormControlLabel value="radio" control={<Radio inputRef={register({ required: true })} />} label="Radio" />
                      <FormControlLabel value="podcast" control={<Radio inputRef={register({ required: true })} />} label="Podcast" />
                      <FormControlLabel value="both" control={<Radio inputRef={register({ required: true })} />} label="Both" />
                    </RadioGroup>
                  </FormControl>
```

So that is my FormControl,

However what is happening is the FormControlLabel are all going to the left (see pic)

What I want it to do is be evenly spaced out from left to right of the screen.

[image: FormControlRow]

Comment: Set `justify-content: space-between` on your `RadioGroup` (assuming it's using `display: flex`).

Comment: @Dai how? Is this in style?

Comment: Yes, in your CSS stylesheet or however your client-side styling is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CSS file, try

```
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1" value="option1" checked>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
    Default radio
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios2" value="option2">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
    Second default radio
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios3" value="option3" disabled>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios3">
    Disabled radio
  </label>
</div>
</div>
```

More info about flexbox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox